# Google App Engine(Java): update attribute that has been created later, in Datastore Viewer

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've been created a persistent Java class using JDO in Google App Engine and now I had to add one more attribute on it. How do I update this attribute? It doesn't appear, in Datastore viewer, in ancient rows (created before I added the new atribute).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The datastore viewer doesn't know anything about your class. It only shows what is actually present on each entity. You will have to update your old entities by setting the new attribute programatically.